# Crash with: another instance of this process was already running

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a crash that happens only from the second time i run the app,not in the first time, so if i clean xcode and run its ok, but than from second time and up, it starting the crash :

```
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger
```

when doing this :

```
     [self schedule:@selector(parallaxUpdate:)]; //call every frame
     ...

     - (void)parallaxUpdate:(ccTime)dt
```

I have read here about this crash i have tried to close and clean xcode .
It happens only at the second time after cleaning project cash .

Comment: Thanks all. i have restarted Xcode,restart simulator,restart system,cleaned, nothing . still crash- it crashes on simulator at the second time only after cleaning.

Comment: so how do you run your game second time?

Comment: i dont. i run it and it crashes.